# String in retrofit GET request

Tags: java, android, retrofit

i want implement search in my app. when i log the send request with interprator i see this:

This is the URL that i want to send for English character:

```
https://admanroid.ir/bavand/get_near_shop_cat.php?lat=35.5088513&lng=46.172843&search="computer"
```

But instead of that, this URL send:

```
  https://admanroid.ir/bavand/get_near_shop_cat.php?lat=35.5088513&lng=46.172843&search=computer
```

Its remove the Quotation mark from my search string.

My response returns empty results. I don't know why. But when i send request with browser and type my string search to URL, everything works well.This problem just happened when pass string to URL

this is my network interface for request:

```
@GET("get_near_shop_cat.php")
    Observable<NearShopLocationModel> getNearShopBySearch(@Query("lat") Double lat,@Query("lng") Double lng,@Query("search") String search);
```

this is the observable:

```
 private Observable<NearShopLocationModel> getObservableNearShopBySerach(Double lat,Double lng,String search){
        return NetworkClient.getRetrofit().create(NetworkInterface.class)
                .getNearShopBySearch(lat,lng,search)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
```

And this is my php code for API:

```
<?php 

    //Importing the database connection 
    require_once('DBconnect.php');

    $lat = $_GET['lat'];    
    $lng = $_GET['lng'];    
    $search = $_GET["search"];  

        //SQL query to fetch data of a range 
        $sql = "SELECT id,title,imageURL1,comment,lat,lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(" . $lng . ") ) + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) 
        AS distance FROM shop WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%',$search, '%') || categoryName LIKE CONCAT('%',$search, '%') HAVING distance < 5";

        //Getting result 
        $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

        //Adding results to an array 
        $results = array(); 


        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                array_push($results, array(
                "id"=>$row['id'],
                "title"=>$row['title'],
                "imageURL1"=>$row['imageURL1'],
                "comment"=>$row['comment'],
                "lat"=>$row['lat'],
                "lng"=>$row['lng']
                )
                );

        }
        //Displaying the array in json format 
        echo json_encode(array("results"=>$results));
```

Comment: Can you give us more information by providing source code that you working on?

Comment: Try to add an interceptor to log everything to see everything is working fine

Comment: @Jasurbek well the above code is from interceptor log `GET /get_near_shop_cat.php?lat=35.5112215&lng=46.1759795&search=%D8%AE%D8%AF%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AA%E2%80%8C20%25%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%BE%DB%8C%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C`

Comment: What is the request that you are attempting to send? In particular, what is the value that you are passing to `search`?

Comment: @WigunaR I update my question

Comment: @Code-Apprentice "computer" that's my search string

Comment: @ShadmanAdman Are you using English letters? When I decode the string from your question, I see non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no. its Persian . but when i use English character for example "computer" its remove the  "   in URL and convert to computer only.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I edit my question. please see it again.

Comment: Have you tried sending a QueryMap Hash<String, String>, instead of lots of Query params?

Comment: @guisantogui Its just three param. I don't think needs Hash.

Comment: @ShadmanAdman sometime ago I had problems using Query params, and QueryMap did the trick

Comment: Both URLS at the beginning of your question look the same to me. Is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice its remove the Quotation mark from my search string/ "computer" --> computer

Comment: @ShadmanAdman Be sure that the string you pass in to the `search` parameter to retrofit has quote characters.

Answer (score 0):

Send your string like this:

```
private Observable<NearShopLocationModel> getObservableNearShopBySerach(Double lat,Double lng,String search){
        return NetworkClient.getRetrofit().create(NetworkInterface.class)
                .getNearShopBySearch(lat,lng,"\""+search+"\"")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
```

Comment: still response returns empty results. I don't know why. But when i send request with browser and type my string search to URL, everything works well ):

Comment: Did you check the base address in your `Retrofit.Builder` code? could you please add that code in your question?

Comment: I'm sure my address is OK. I send many request with that address. This problem 
just happened when pass string to URL.